# How to make .slide transition insertion animation from top to bottom?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to make .slide transition insertion animation from top to bottom instead of left to right?

```
        if visible {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 10)
                .transition(.slide)
                .animation(.easeIn)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct transition type that should be used is `move` instead of `slide`, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition/move(edge:)

```
        if visible {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 10)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                .animation(.easeIn)
        }
```

[image]